# Como obtener el link del primer resultado de una búsqueda en Youtube con Beautiful Soap u otra libreria

Tags: python, python-3.x, scraping, beautifulsoup

Mi objetivo es obtener el link del primer resultado de un búsqueda en Youtube con Beautiful Soap, pero no lo consigo.

Ademas , no se como solucionar el que si hago una busqueda en youtube me devuelva un html correcto, para asi poder buscar el href de la cancion.

El contenido de songs.txt es una lista de nombres como "Juice world Cant die"

Actualmente uso beautiful soap 4 y requests y busco la cancion mediante:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

with open("songs.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    for i in f:
        song = i.replace(" ", "+")

        url='https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+song

        searched=requests.get(url)
        soup=bs(searched.text,'html.parser')

        a = soup.find_all("a", "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer") # trailing space is required.
        for i in a:
            url = i.get('href')
            print(url)
```

Se que con selenium seria mucho mas facil pero prefiero que se realize todo el background como lo hace beautiful soap

Comment: Hola Shockz! Por favor corrigue tu pregunta, así será más fácil que las personas puedan ayudarte en tu problema. En concreto la identación es incorrecta, y  `requests` y `bs` no aparecen por ningun lado, deberías poner como has hecho las importaciónes para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: la identacion esta bien , esque , cogi solo el fragmento relevante, y vale

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No siempre hace falta hacer *scraping* :-)

YouTube tiene una [API de búsqueda](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=es). Si te registras como desarrollador (lo cual es gratuito) obtienes una API_KEY con la que puedes realizar búsquedas y otras operaciones y recibir la respuesta en JSON. Incluso proporcionan una librería para Python para facilitar la interacción con su API.

Por otro lado, existe una increíble herramienta realizada en Python llamada Youtube-dl que permite descargar vídeos de Youtube y de otros sitios, y que hace uso de la API para búsquedas, y de scraping y otras técnicas para la descarga en sí. Examinando el código fuente de esa herramienta, la API_KEY de su desarrollador es visible (en Github), por lo que supongo que no le importará que la use para una prueba de concepto. No obstante lo que tú deberías hacer es usar tu propia API_KEY.

> **EDIT**. El código que suministro a continuación funciona sólo con la API v1 y por tanto con API_KEYs antiguas. En una edición posterior (más abajo) doy código que funciona con la API v3 que es la actual, y con las nuevas API_KEYs. Mantengo aquí la respuesta original por si fuera de interés

### Llamando a la API v1

Llamar a la API de búsqueda consiste en realizar una petición HTTP de tipo POST a una cierta URL de Youtube, y pasar en esa URL el valor de tu API_KEY. En el cuerpo del POST debes incluir un JSON con unos ciertos parámetros, que se pueden sacar también del [fuente de youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/470cf496f5e33a24527decc736f9cb204393ea70/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L3335), entre los cuales está la `query`, es decir, la cadena de búsqueda que quieras usar.

Usando la librería `requests` la petición a la API queda simplemente así:

```
  r = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'), 
                    headers={'content-type': 'application/json'} )
```

donde `url` sería `"https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/search?key={API_KEY}"` y `data` sería el JSON antes enlazado. Una API_KEY válida se puede ver también en el fuente de youtube-dl, un poco más abajo de la línea que enlacé.

La respuesta es un enoooorme JSON (puede ser realmente enorme si la búsqueda produce muchos resultados), que contiene montones de meta-data sobre cada vídeo. Es difícil navegar por todo ese JSON y entender todo lo que hay en él, pero la parte relevante es que al final, dentro de él (y bastante anidado en un montón de diccionarios), está la lista de los resultados (entremezclada con otros resultados que son publicidad) y cada resultado contiene entre otras cosas el videoId que te interesa, y su título, para mejor verificación.

He escrito una función que extrae de las entrañas de ese JSON la lista de los N primeros títulos y videoIds:

```py
import requests
import json

def get_video_info(query, limit=10):
  data = {'context': {
             'client': {
                 'clientName': 'WEB',
                 'clientVersion': '2.20201021.03.00',
             }
          },
          'query': query,
        }

  API_KEY = "NO_VOY_A_PONER_AQUI_LA_API_KEY"
  url = f"https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/search?key={API_KEY}"
  r = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'), 
                    headers={'content-type': 'application/json'} )
  j = r.json()

  # Extraer lista de resultados
  results = (j["contents"]['twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer']['primaryContents']
             ['sectionListRenderer']['contents'][0]
             ['itemSectionRenderer']['contents'])
  # Construir lista simplificada
  info_list = []
  for video in results:
    info = video.get("videoRenderer")
    if not info:
      continue           # Saltarse los resultados que son publicidad
    # Extraer solo título e id
    title = info["title"]["runs"][0]["text"]
    video_id = info["videoId"]
    info_list.append((video_id, title))

    if len(info_list) == limit:  # Detenerse cuando haya suficientes
      break
  return info_list
```

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
resultados = get_video_info("never gonna give you up")
print("\n".join("   ".join(data) for data in resultados))
```

produce:

```
dQw4w9WgXcQ   Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)
6_b7RDuLwcI   Rick Astley Never gonna give you up lyrics!!!
Ykup4vetvmw   Jerry Butler - Never Gonna Give You Up (1968)
IdkCEioCp24   Foo Fighters With Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up  - London O2 Arena 19 September 2017
IO9XlQrEt2Y   Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (The Roxy 1987)
VbUuB1aN2DA   Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up - Live at The Isle of Wight Festival 2019
DLzxrzFCyOs   Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up [HQ]
BjDebmqFRuc   Never Gonna Give You Up Voice Crack
xaazUgEKuVA   never gonna give you up for 1 hour
```

Si lo que quieres es simplemente la URL del primer resultado se puede construir así:

```
url_primero = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(resultados[0][0])
```

Y así llegas a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

## EDIT: Usando la API v3

El código anterior usa la API v1 de Youtube, la cual es obsoleta. Usé esa API porque me basé en el código de youtube-dl, pero esto fuerza a usar también la API_KEY de su desarrollador, lo que no es apropiado.

La forma correcta de hacer esto sería entonces crear una nueva API_KEY a través de la [consola para desarrolladores de google](https://console.developers.google.com/), y hacerlo para la `YouTube Data API v3`.

Esta API_KEY no es compatible con el código antes dado, y hay que escribir un código nuevo. Por suerte la API v3 es mucho más simple y limpia que la v1. La petición se hace con GET en vez de POST, y el JSON resultante es mucho más fácil de usar (y más corto, porque ya en la petición especificas el número máximo de resultados que quieres).

Esta sería la nueva función:

```
import requests
import json

def get_video_info(query, limit=10):
  API_KEY = "AIzaS...TU PROPIA API_KEY"
  url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
  data = {
      "key": API_KEY,
      "part": "id,snippet",
      "q": query,
      "max_results": limit
  }
  r = requests.get(url, params=data)
  j = r.json()

  # Construir y retornar lista simplificada
  return [ (v["id"]["videoId"], v["snippet"]["title"]) for v in j["items"] ]
```

Se llamaría de igual forma que la anterior, y retornaría una lista de tuplas en las que el primer elemento es el id del vídeo y el segundo es el título. **CUIDADO** porque el título puede contener cualquier carácter Unicode (emojis, japonés, etc.) que causaría problemas al tratar de imprimirlo en una terminal que no soporte ese juego de caracteres.

Comment: @Shockz Respuesta actualizada. La nueva versión para la API v3 funciona bien. Lo he testeado con una API_KEY propia que acabo de generar. Por favor, borra los anteriores comentarios

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6):

Tienes que usar `Selenium`, sé que no es la respuesta que querías, pero espero después de la explicación convencerte de que es lo correcto.

### Por qué no puedo usar `BeautifulSoup`

En el scraping, al igual que en todo el mundo de la programación no hay cosas buenas o malas, todo depende del contexto.

**Youtube** es una página con **gran cantidad** de `JavaScript` esto hace que sea necesario **un navegador** para poder renderizar y tener acceso a **todo su contenido**.

Opciones como `requests`, `Srapy`, `BeautifulSoup`, no integran navegadores, ni formas de renderizar `JavaScript`. La consecuencia de esto es que **NO puedes acceder al contenido generado mediante `JavaScript`** por lo que solo tendrás acceso al `HTML` y `CSS`.

Lo que tratas de obtener es un link generado por Youtube que necesita ser renderizado por un navegador para que aparezca, por lo tanto no puedes usar ningún framework de scraping que no integre renderización de contenido.

### Selenium

En este caso nos queda `Selenium` su uso es sencillo, te quedo el código explicado y comentado siguiendo tu ejemplo poniendo solo un link (solo tienes que integrar el abrir el fichero y el bucle `for` al principio, lo hago así para que sea reproducible):

```
#Importaciones
from selenium import webdriver
#from scrapy.selector import Selector
from parsel import Selector

#Variables necesarias
i = "Juice world Cant die"
song = i.replace(" ", "+")
base_url = "https://www.youtube.com" #La base de la página a scrapear
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + song

#Inicialiamos el chromedriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("path/al/wedriver/chromedriver")

#Obtenemos la url que queremos scrapear
driver.get(url)

#Pasamos el contenido de la web a un selector que nos permitirá seleccionar las etiquetas
sel = Selector(driver.page_source)

#Extraemos la primera canción el href relativo
primer_resultado = sel.xpath('//div/h3/a[@class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"]/@href').extract_first()

#Juntamos el href relativo con base_url para convertirlo en absoluto
link_primer_resultado = base_url + primer_resultado

#Cerramos el navegador
driver.close()
```

Primero de todo, necesitas descargar `chromeDriver` lo puedes hacer desde la [página de Google](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/). Para asegurarse de que no haya problemas descárgate la versión que tienes instalada de Google Chrome, puedes ver la versión que tienes con: `google-chrome -version`

**Explicación del código**:

- `driver=webdriver.Chrome("path/al/wedriver/chromedriver")`: Nos creamos un navegador usando la dirección donde se encuentra descargado nuestro chromedriver.
- `driver.get(url)`: le pasamos la url que queremos scrapear
- `sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)`: transformamos la página a texto plano y se la pasamos a `Selector` con esto lo que hacemos es crear un "selector" que nos permite parsear la página de distintas formas, yo utilizo `xpath` pero puede usarse cualquier otra.
- `primer_resultado = sel.xpath('//div/h3/a[@class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"]/@href').extract_first()`: le indicamos que se vaya a donde se encuentran las URLs de todas las canciones, y con `extract_first()` le decimos que coja la primera.
- `link_primer_resultado = base_url + primer_resultado`: Como nos da una URL relativa, tenemos que convertirla en absoluta, por lo que la pegamos a `base_url`, que es la URL de Youtube.
  *`driver.close()`: Cerramos el navegador para que no se nos queden abiertos y el equipo se quede sin RAM.

### Selenium en Background

> Se que con selenium seria mucho mas facil pero prefiero que se realize todo el background como lo hace beautiful soap

Para que se ejecute por detrás sin que veamos nada, tan solo hay que hacer unas pequeñas modificaciones en el código, que quedaría así:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from scrapy.selector import Selector
from parsel import Selector

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("--headless")

i = "Juice world Cant die"
song = i.replace(" ", "+")
base_url = "https://www.youtube.com"

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + song

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/al/wedriver/chromedriver", options=opts)
driver.get(url)

sel = Selector(driver.page_source)
primer_resultado = sel.xpath('//div/h3/a[@class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"]/@href').extract_first()
link_primer_resultado = base_url + primer_resultado
driver.close()
```

**Explicación de lo añadido:**

- `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`: nos importamos las opciones, con esto se pueden manejar distintas opciones del navegador
  *`opts = Options()`: instanciamos las opciones
  *`opts.add_argument("--headless")`: añadimos el argumento "--headless". Esta opción hace que nuestro Chrome Driver esté en modo silencioso, es decir no se va a abrir ningún navegador, por lo que no veremos nada, pero **la extracción seguirá sucediendo en background**.
- `driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/al/wedriver/chromedriver", options=opts)`: le pasamos las opciones al navegador al instanciarlo.

### Bonus

Después de esta explicación, quiero reiterar lo que dije al principio. **No hay frameworks de scraping que sean mejores unos que otros** simplemente cada uno tiene su funcionalidad y campo de aplicación.

Si lo que buscas no necesita ser renderizado con `JavaScript` entonces no tiene sentido que uses `Selenium` ya que es más pesado, más lento y complejo al tener que iniciar un navegador. Opciones como `Scrapy`, `requests` o `BeautifulSoup` son más acertadas.

Si lo que buscas necesita ser renderizado, pues no se encuentra directamente en el `HTML` o `CSS` necesitas usar `Selenium` ya que las anteriores opciones al no integrar un navegador, no te permiten renderizar la página y acceder al contenido

Comment: obtengo grandes errores al intentar instalar scrapy , hay alguna alternativa a usar scrapy en el codigo?

Comment: Puedes usar el `Selector` de la librería `parsel` que es el mismo que el que tiene `Scrapy`. Te he editado la pregunta comentado el código de `scrapy` y quedando el de `parsel`

Comment: perfecto gracias

Answer (score 2):

Se que quieres que todo se haga por BS4, pero con Selenium te sale en 3 líneas de código además puedes usar BS4 junto con Selenium, el siguiente scrpit te funciona solo para el primer resultado de la busqueda, para este ejemplo use la canción In the end de Linkin Park, solo basta con escribas un for que itere sobre el .txt que tienes, adicionalmente tienes que descargar un driver del navegador de tu preferencia Chrome, Firefox, etc y la ruta la pones en la tercera linea del script Ahí donde se especifica. Por último te dejo un link donde puedes descargar el driver de chrome:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome("ACA PONES LA RUTA DE TU DRIVER")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=intheend')
Link=driver.find_element_by_id("video-title").get_attribute("href")
print(Link)
```